I need help in solving following expression: $0.0000000002345067555870132923121546898 n = a.9651992727475557708521430762$
$$0.0000000002345067555870132923121546898 n = a.9651992727475557708521430762$$
I want to calculate the value of $n, n$ should be an integer.
I only know the fractional part of the answer.
any help is appreciated, Thanks.
Answer:
$$n = \frac{29502280.96519927274755577085}{0.0000000002345067555870132923121546898}= 125805676221777358$$
if I iterate from $1$ to $29502280$, I can get the answer but I want to know if there is any reverse multiplication method to reach the answer directly.
for integers, it will be easy if you know one of the factors but for decimals, I am having a hard time.

What's $a$?  What have you tried?  If you know the fractional part of the answer (whatever that means in this context) please supply it and explain what you mean by it.

a.9651992727475557708521430762, is the $’.’$ means multiplication or just a decimal point?

@user1176409 it's decimal point

scale both sides by some..$10^{\text{large}}$ so you get rid of the decimals

If you take the reciprocal of the number on the left hand side (i.e. one divided by that number), it turns out to be an integer. Multiply both sides by that integer.

@lulu we can get the answer if we try 1.9651992727475557708521430762...10.9651992727475557708521430762 & so on
till we get the value of n as an integer but it will be a lengthy process ... I need a fast way to get the answer, like reverse multiplication ... I tried that also

@BhagwanParge could you provide some context regarding the question?

@SohamSaha That is obviously the rounding error as it has the same number of significant digits as the original number. Just calculate 1/4264269477 and see that it matches until it is cut off.

@JaapScherphuis I have added more explanation to the question for clarity, Thanks.

Thanks @tyma-gaidesh

Just to be clear 1) you are multiplying by an integer $n$ and not that $n$ is the very last decimal.  And 2) $a$ is an integer of any size (can it be negative?) and 3) There has been no rounding?  Numbers this long on calculators will almost certainly have roundings.

@fleablood 1) n is any positive integer 2) a is also a positive integer

rounding is possible


If you take the reciprocal of the first number, you get:
$$1/0.0000000002345067555870132923121546898=
\\4264269477.0000000000000000007823$$
That means that the number is actually $1/4264269477$, and it is easily checked that this does match all the given digits.
In a moment we will multiply both sides of the equation by $4264269477$, so let's see what that does to the number on the rhs:
$$4264269477*0.9651992727475557708521430762=
\\4115869797.9999999999999999998765$$
So again we get an integer, apart from the rounding errors. So the equation becomes:
$$n = 4264269477*a + 4115869798$$
Any non-negative integer value for $a$ results in a solution for $n$ (up to minor rounding errors), and the smallest solution uses $a=0$ and gives $n=4115869798$.

Thanks @jaap-scherphuis.
I have already said this in the main section of the comment.
I can iterate or have a loop.

@BhagwanParge I think you are getting confused by rounding errors. The integer part $a$ can have any value. Every (non-negative) value for $a$ gives a solution for $n$.

@Jaap-sscherphuis Yes if we try from 1 to n then every value will satisfy the expression but if we try to reverse engineer then we will have fewer solutions like
0.12320329 * n   = a.31827515...I can start reverse engineering from,
0.12320329 * 5   = 0.61601645 ...
0.12320329 * 35 = 4.31211515

Thanks. as I am using fractions of different sizes, I don't know the rightmost digit to reverse engineer and if I use fractions after rounding them to certain digits after decimal ... I can't reverse engineer.

@BhagwanParge Whatever you are doing to arrive at the numbers in your equation, you should not use decimal approximations. Keep them as rational numbers, then ou wont have much trouble finding solutions.
